# Block Internet access and LAN Access for an endpoint at the gateway level through iptables

Tags: internet, iptables, lan

How to Block Internet access and LAN Access for an endpoint at the gateway level through iptables

Endpoint should not have LAN Access and Internet Access by using IPtables..
can anyone help on this ??

Answer (score 0):

Nothing comes in or goes out.

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -d IPADDRESS_of_client
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP -d IPADDRESS_of_client

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -s IPADDRESS_of_client
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP -s IPADDRESS_of_client

/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Some info below : 
-A, --append

 -j, --jump target 
-d, --destination

Comment: You would need bidirectional blocking in each direction, one for source and one for destination, in each table.  So the rules above need to be duplicated but with `-s` in place of `-d`.

Comment: sorry to say that at my end , those are not working..

Comment: It should be done at the gateway level not at the endpoint

Comment: Requirement :
Need to restrict access for Internet and LAN for a computer connected to a network.
I need to execute the iptables commands at gateway.

Comment: Could you please help on this..

Comment: Try adding the following conditions in addition to earlier to block to and fro connections. `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -s IPADDRESS_of_client;` 
`iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP -s IPADDRESS_of_client`

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for notifying my carelessness in missing the requirement for blocking both directions.

Comment: Thanks for the response..!!
Tried the above commands..with both -d and -s ..
No communication between the gateway and x.x.x.x but able to ping to other nodes in the network..LAN Access is not restricted..
plz help me out ...

Comment: I need to add the iptable rules at the gateway..
cannot add at the endpoint